# SQL Not recognizing Named Column

Tags: sql

Code not recognizing column alias

I am testing codes using PowerShell (sqlcmd) and the code returns an error that it does not recognize column 'Sdate' in Line 3? I have defined 'Sdate' in Column 1 so I am confused, may someone please help as I am new to SQL.

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, MyDate)) AS SDate
FROM Schedule
WHERE Sdate > '20180101';
```

Comment: Your SQL engine is working correctly!  Yay!  SQL doesn't allow column aliases defined in the `SELECT` to be used in the `WHERE`.  You need to repeat the expression, use a CTE, subquery or related method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` is evaluated before `SELECT`. This is the reason `Sdate` is not recognize.  SQL order of operation

`FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
WINDOW functions
SELECT
DISTINCT
UNION
ORDER BY
LIMIT and OFFSET`

Answer (score 2):

That's SQL not letting you using aliases that way. Repeat the 'function' instead

Do instead

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, MyDate)) AS SDate
FROM Schedule
WHERE DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, MyDate)) > '20180101';
```

Answer (score 0):

alias does not support all dbms in `where`

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,0, DATEDIFF(dd,0, MyDate)) AS SDate
    FROM Schedule
    WHERE MyDate> '20180101'
```